# `lftp` does not connect to FTPS (FTP over TLS) server but filezilla and ncftp yes

Tags: certificates, lftp, ftps, handshake

I have a shared hosted server with FTPS access, and I can connect it trough Filezilla with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<FileZilla3>
    <Servers>
        <Server>
            <Host>ftp.idrissi.co</Host>
            <Port>21</Port>
            <Protocol>4</Protocol>
            <Type>0</Type>
            <User>user@idrissi.co</User>
            <Logontype>2</Logontype>
            <TimezoneOffset>0</TimezoneOffset>
            <PasvMode>MODE_DEFAULT</PasvMode>
            <MaximumMultipleConnections>0</MaximumMultipleConnections>
            <EncodingType>Auto</EncodingType>
            <BypassProxy>0</BypassProxy>
            <Name>ftp.idrissi.co</Name>
            <Comments />
            <LocalDir />
            <RemoteDir />
            <SyncBrowsing>0</SyncBrowsing>ftp.idrissi.co
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</FileZilla3>
```

With `ncftp` is more simple, I just use the following command `ncftp -u user@idrissi.co -P 21 ftp://ftp.idrissi.co`.

But, when I try to access with the [`lftp`](https://lftp.tech/) tool it fail. With `lftp`, I use the following configuration:

```
1d [fauve:~/lftptest] % openssl s_client -starttls ftp -crlf -connect ftp.idrissi.co:21 > ftp-idrissi-temp.cert 

1d [fauve:~/lftptest] 130 % cat ftp-idrissi-temp.cert | pcregrep -M '\-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----(.*\n)*.*-----END CERTIFICATE-----' > ftp-idrissi.cert 
1d [fauve:~/lftptest] % vim ftp-idrissi.cert 
1d [fauve:~/lftptest] % cat lftp-script
set ftps:initial-prot P
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ssl:cert-file ./ftp-idrissi.cert
ls       
1d [fauve:~/lftptest] % lftp -e "`cat lftp-script| sed 's/\n/; /'`"  -p 21 -u user@idrissi.co ftps://ftp.idrissi.co                                                                          
ls: Erreur fatale: gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
1d [fauve:~/lftptest] 1 % lftp -e "`cat lftp-script| sed 's/\n/; /'`"  -p 21 -u user@idrissi.co ftp://ftp.idrissi.co 
ls: Erreur fatale: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name « ftp.idrissi.co »
```

I try many variations on the `lftp-script` but it doesn’t work. And I don’t understand how Fillezilla could do it with a minimalist config. So, how can I connect to my FTP account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly, I get it.

The problem is resolved by `set ssl:check-hostname false`.